# assigning variable from SELECT query in PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables, select

How do I query a database using a SELECT statement and then assign the value from the query as a variable?

Comment: Have you even tried to read **anything** to solve your problem? http://php.net/mysql_query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible way:

```
<?php
$dbcon = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
if (!$dbcon)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("database_name", $dbcon);

$query_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MyTable");

while($result_array = mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
  {
  echo $result_array['column1'] . " " . $result_array['column2'];
  echo "<br />";
  }

mysql_close($dbcon);
?>
```

Comment: Curious why in some cases you use `'` and in other `"`. Randomly?

Comment: Just grabbed some code I had around and pieced together a quick example. No other reason in particular other than of course you want to use single `'` in `$result_array['column2']`.